# Disable autocorrect on a SwiftUI searchable search bar

Tags: ios, swift, search, swiftui, ios15

I have a SwiftUI and Core Data app and have implemented the new iOS 15 search bar API.

```
.searchable(text: $searchText) // This is a modifier under my List view
```

However, the search bar has autocorrect, which unexpectedly changes the search when the view disappears or the user commits (it even happens if navigating to a detail view and back). Overall it is a poor user experience.

I cannot find anything in the Apple documentation for disabling autocorrect on this search bar (although it is easily done for a standard `TextField` with the `.disableAutocorrect(true)` modifier).

I used a Swift Package for iOS14 that provided a search bar (via `UIViewRepresentable`), but I would rather use first party APIs if possible, so my question relates specifically to the SwiftUI `.searchable` API, which was introduced in iOS 15.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**For iOS 15**

The auto correction of the search bar get disabled if you set `disableAutocorrection(true)` after `.searchable(text: $searchText)`.

```swift
List {
    //
}
.searchable(text: $searchText)
.disableAutocorrection(true)
```

**For iOS 16+**

From iOS 16 onwards `disableAutocorrection` is deprecated. So need to use `autocorrectionDisabled` instead.

```swift
List {
    //
}
.searchable(text: $searchText)
.autocorrectionDisabled(true)
```

Comment: This works! I though I had tried it like this but clearly not. I though that modifier could only be used for `TextField`s. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome and glad it solved your problem :)

Comment: this works however the corrected text suggestions are still displayed above the keyboard.

Answer (score 6):

`disableAutocorrect` will be deprecated in a future iOS update (current version: iOS 16.3). Use `autocorrectionDisabled` instead:

```
List {
    //
}
.searchable(text: $searchText)
.autocorrectionDisabled(true)
```